# SQLite: How to see people that aren't my friend, but are friends with my friends

Tags: sql, sqlite, inner-join, where-clause

I have a database in DB Browser where I have two tables;

```
CREATE TABLE "User" (
    "ID"    integer NOT NULL,
    "name"  TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("ID" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
```

[image: Example data from User]

```
CREATE TABLE "Friends" (
    "UserID"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "FriendID"  INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY("UserID") REFERENCES "Anvandare"("ID") ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

[image: Example data from Friends]

So my question is, how do I make a query that Displays People that I'm not friends with, but my friends are friends with them. It's so I can find new friends basically.

Comment: I undid what was most likely an accidental edit by unintentional pasting and posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join multiple times:

```
select distinct u.id, u.name
from friends f1                                   -- my friends
inner join friends f2 on f2.userid = f1.friendid  -- the friends of my friends
inner join users u on u.id = f2.friendid
where 
    f1.userid = ?
    and f2.friendid <> f1.userid
    and not exists (                               -- that are not my friends
        select 1 from friends f3 where f3.userid = ? and f3.friendid = f2.frienid
    )
```

Comment: Thanks so much, when I run the code it lists all the friends of my friends, but it also lists the user that wanted the information ("me"), I just want to list the friends of friends, not me too. Is there an easy fix for that?

Comment: @NotImpostor: we can just use another condition to the  `where` clause. I updated my answer.